# For pod-to-pod communication, what IP should be used? The service's ClusterIP or the endpoint

Tags: kubernetes

I've deployed the Rancher Helm chart to my Kubernetes cluster and want to access the Rancher API/UI from another pod (i.e. a pod running an ingress-controller).

when I list the services and the endpoints. The IP addresses differ:

```
$ kubectl get ep | grep rancher
release-name-rancher                         10.200.23.13:80                    18h
```

and

```
$ kubectl get services | grep rancher 
release-name-rancher                         ClusterIP   10.100.200.253   <none>        80/TCP                       18h
```

Within the container of the client (i.e. the ingress controller), I see the service beeing represented with the service's ClusterIP:

```
$ env | grep RELEASE_NAME_RANCHER_SERVICE_HOST
RELEASE_NAME_RANCHER_SERVICE_HOST=10.100.200.253
```

Trying to reach the backend via the IP address in the Env does not work (`curl 10.100.200.253` just delivers no response and blocks forever).

Trying to reach the backend via the endpoint address works:

```
$ curl 10.200.23.13
<a href="https://10.200.23.13/">Found</a>.
```

**I'm quite confused why the endpoint IP address and the ClusterIP address differ and why is it not possible to connect to the ClusterIP address. Any hints to polish my understanding?**

Answer (score 3):

In Kubernetes, every Pod and Service gets its own IP address.  The `kubectl get services` IP address is the Kubernetes-internal address of the Service; the `get ep` address address of the Pod behind it.  The Service actually acts like a load balancer, and there can be multiple Pods attached to it.  The [Kubernetes Service documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) goes into a *lot* of detail about what exactly is happening here.

Kubernetes also provides an [internal DNS service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns) that can resolve Service names.  You generally shouldn't use any of these IP addresses directly; instead, use the host name `release-name-rancher.default.svc.cluster.local` (or replace "default" if you're running in some other Kubernetes namespace).

While the `..._SERVICE_HOST` environment variable you reference is supported and documented, I'd avoid using it.  Of particular note, if you `helm install` or `kubectl apply` a large set of resources at once and the Pod gets created before the Service, you'll be in a consistent state except that the Pod won't actually have this environment variable.  In a Helm land where Services don't have fixed names, the environment variable name won't be fixed either.  Prefer the DNS name.

Comment: You can just use _release-name-rancher_ if using it from within the same namespace.As David said - use the DNS names (created by the services entity). You should not be referencing IP address. Even external/public IP addresses should be registered as a service and internally you should still use its name